# TypeError: Cannot read property 'power' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, mqtt

I received a JSON object via MQTT in a react.js app. I can clearly see that the power value exists but nevertheless, I get the exception from the question title. I assume I wrongly access the JSON but how should I access it?

How the JSON object looks:
[image: json object]

Here is how I do it now:

```
 // this is one component where I receive it
 let decodedMessage = JSON.parse(message);

//power component where I am supposed to receive it
const {portside} = this.props
const power =  portside.power
```

Comment: how does your message look like ? Also add the code for your Power Component ?

Comment: @Shyam Message is a byte array so not sure if helpful

Comment: Your object looks fine . But what might have happened is you are rendering the Power component even before you receive the message . so you need to guard your props . `const { portside = {} } = this.props`   `const power = portside?.power || 0`